# Invoke findbug scan on the fly, on a piece of java source code

Tags: java, findbugs

In our product, In UI, we give the users (i.e., developers) a way to write the java code, for customization. On Saving the form , I want to invoke the findbugs static analysis on that java source, and display the findings. How can I integrate Findbugs with my produce in this case? Could someone suggest which APIs to invoke?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: just a point of note, findbugs doesn't run on java source code.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a main entry-point at
[edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/FindBugs2.html) ; once instantiated, you can add sources to scan via `setProject()`, call `execute()`, and look at the results via `getBugReporter()`. That is the low-level way of doing things - you would essentially bundle FindBugs with your application (beware possible licensing issues), and call it internally. I may be missing some steps above - since I have only browsed documentation, which does not include a code example for this use-case.

An easier integration can be achieved by calling FindBugs as an external application, via `java -jar <path-to-findbugs-jar> -auxclasspath <classpath needed for analysis> -analyzeFromFile <file with one filename to analyze per line>`; the application then opens and the user is free to explore any highlighted bugs.
A full list of [command-line options](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html) - it is even possible to have FindBugs generate a report, and then only display the report, without launching the FindBugs UI at all.